# Can't use laptop display?

Tags: display

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 with a LiveCD. During the installation, nothing was shown on screen unless I plugged in an external monitor. Same thing happens within Ubuntu.

I have an Emachines E525.
Could this just be a backlight issue or something? It works fine on Windows though.
If anyone could help, that'd be great. Please explain everything throughly if you can though, I'm new to all of this.

Comment: so how it worked?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/+bug/392948

See comments [#23](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/+bug/392948/comments/23) and [#24](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/+bug/392948/comments/24).

Workaround is to add **acpi_osi=Linux** to the kernel cmdline:

### One-line solution (use at your own risk)

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"\(.*\)\"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"\1 acpi_osi=Linux\"/' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```

### Manual method

1. edit */etc/default/grub* file:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Add **acpi_osi=Linux** to the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** variable so it will look like

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"

1. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change line in there adding just `acpi_osi=Linux` so it looks like`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`
then

```
sudo update-grub
```

on start u need to change brightness once on some comps. If thats the case like for Emachines e525 then also do this
so that on start brightness would be max

```
sudo gedit etc/rc.local
```

before `exit 0` put `setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00`